# PHP Gearman Task sometimes returns empty object

Tags: php, gearman

I have a simple Gearman client and worker. I am running both on my Ubuntu desktop. I have installed the gearman-beta pecl package and the version of Gearman from synaptic.

My problem is that *sometimes* I'm getting an empty object back from the worker. About 50% of the time it displays the expected text, the rest of the time it displays "GearmanTask Object
(
)" (from my print_r in the client)

At no point is an exception happening, the client always thinks the worker completed successfully. I should also note that there aren't any timeouts, the client script executes quickly.

Client

```
$gmclient = new GearmanClient();
$gmclient->addServer();

$gmclient->addTask('test','just some text');
$gmclient->setCompleteCallback("complete");
$gmclient->setFailCallback('fail');
$gmclient->runTasks(); 

function fail() {
  echo "FAIL";
}
function complete($task) { 
  print "COMPLETE: " . $task->data() . "<br />";
  if($task->data() == '') {
     echo '<pre>'.print_r($task, true).'</pre><br />';
     echo $task->error(); 
  }
}
```

Worker (test.php)

```
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("test", "test_function");
while (true) {
  $worker->work();
  print $worker->returnCode();
}
function test_function($job) {
  return $job->workload() . ' worked!';
}
```

I don't have anything in /var/log/gearman-job-server.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem strange but the following worked for me.

You should replace the following block

```
$gmclient = new GearmanClient();
$gmclient->addServer();

$gmclient->addTask('test','just some text');
$gmclient->setCompleteCallback("complete");
$gmclient->setFailCallback('fail');
$gmclient->runTasks();
```

with this

```
$gmclient = new GearmanClient();
$gmclient->addServer();

$gmclient->setCompleteCallback("complete");
$gmclient->setFailCallback('fail');

$gmclient->addTask('test','just some text');
$gmclient->runTasks();
```